# HQL query on map key : Column not found: SQLGrammarException

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following model:

```
class A{
    Map<String, Integer> tags
}

class B{
   A a;
}
```

I need to find instances of B where its associated A has a certain key value in its tags map

I issue the following HQL Query

```
FROM B WHERE index(a.tags) = 'the_value'
```

Unfortunately, this yields to a SQLGrammarException. 
The query being built has a WHERE clause that ends with:

> and tags2_.tags_idx='the_value'

and the exception message is

> Column not found: TAGS2_.TAGS_IDX

Unfortunately, the alias tags2_ is not previously declared in the statement, which leads to the exception.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the absent alias, but I guess you need the following syntax in this case:

```
FROM B WHERE 'the_value' IN INDICES(a.tags)
```

**See also:**

- [16.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
from B b join b.a a where index(a.tags) = 'the_value'
```

Or maybe:

```
from B b where index(b.a.tags) = 'the_value'
```